# If I get Premium for Battlefield will I ever need to get it again?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

If I get Premium for the Xbox One will I ever have to buy Premium again for my Xbox One account? And if I get it for BF4 will it transfer to Hardline?

Answer (score 13):

Battlefield 4 Premium is a **permanent purchase**. You won't need to buy it again for this game. Ever.

Battlefield 4 Premium is **not** linked with Hardline in any way.
BF3 Premium did not transfer to BF4 either.

More information about BF4 Premium is available on the [official website](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-4/premium-membership).